# CMake does not find boost_thread

Tags: macos, boost, cmake

I am trying to install the OpenGM library. However, while using CMake, I get the following error:

```
 CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1753 (message):
   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

   Boost version: 1.62.0

   Boost include path: /usr/local/include

   Could not find the following Boost libraries:

           boost_thread

   Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
   need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
   to the location of Boost.
```

However, when I do:

```
ls -l
```

in

```
/usr/local/include
```

I get the following line:

```
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 Florian  admin   36 13 oct 19:11 boost -> ../Cellar/boost/1.62.0/include/boost
```

which suggests that it looks in the right directory.

In:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

I have:

```
libboost_thread-mt.a            
libboost_thread-mt.dylib
```

So, it seems that the boost_thread library does exist...

Regarding the CMake configuration related to Boost, I have:

```
 Boost_DIR                        Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND                           
 Boost_INCLUDE_DIR                /usr/local/include                           
 Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG          /usr/local/lib                               
 Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE        /usr/local/lib                               
 Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG       /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib         
 Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE     /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib
```

If it can help, I am under Mac OSX and Boost was installed through:

```
brew install boost --with-python
brew install boost-python
```

Comment: What could help is to see your CMake file(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to handle this error by setting the Boost multithreading flag to ON n CMakeLists.txt.